# Python - Function not returning y value

Tags: python-3.x, function

I'm essentially making a counter and it counts the number of times a name appears in a list. I'm trying to use a function so I can easily do it for all the names. It works fine when I don't make the code a function but as soon as I do it no longer returns the value of y.

```
#
animal_types=['Elephant', 'Rhinoceros', 'Lion','Water Buffalo','Leopard','Giraffe','Giraffe','Ghu','Thompson Gazelle','Dik Dik','Zebra','Baboon','Hyena','Hippopotamus','Crocodile','Ostrich','Wild Dog','WartHog','Vulture']

short_animal_list = ['Baboon', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Leopard', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Elephant', 'Gnu']

medium_animal_list = ['Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Lion', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Vulture', 'Leopard', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Hippopotamus', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Vulture', 'Baboon', 'Baboon', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Dik Dik', 'Rhinoceros', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Hippopotamus', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Elephant', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Crocodile', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Leopard', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Elephant', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Crocodile', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Rhinoceros', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Elephant', 'Hippopotamus', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Elephant', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Hippopotamus', 'Crocodile', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Dik Dik', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Giraffe', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Crocodile', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Hyena', 'Giraffe', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Baboon', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Hyena']

long_animal_list = ['WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Lion', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Lion', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Crocodile', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Lion', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Dik Dik', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Elephant', 'Vulture', 'Vulture', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Hyena', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Hippopotamus', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Hyena', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'WartHog', 'Elephant', 'Giraffe', 'Elephant', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Elephant', 'WartHog', 'Vulture', 'WartHog', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Leopard', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Water Buffalo', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Wild Dog', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Baboon', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Crocodile', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Water Buffalo', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Elephant', 'Gnu', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Water Buffalo', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Rhinoceros', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Water Buffalo', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Elephant', 'Hippopotamus', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Hippopotamus', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Wild Dog', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Lion', 'Hyena', 'Crocodile', 'Hyena', 'Vulture', 'Hyena', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'WartHog', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hippopotamus', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Lion', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'Dik Dik', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Vulture', 'Hippopotamus', 'Wild Dog', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Cheetah', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Hippopotamus', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Dik Dik', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Crocodile', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Leopard', 'Giraffe', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Cheetah', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Hyena', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Elephant', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Crocodile', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Water Buffalo', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Dik Dik', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Crocodile', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'Baboon', 'Hyena', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Dik Dik', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Hyena', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Lion', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Leopard', 'Lion', 'Vulture', 'Elephant', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Elephant', 'Leopard', 'Elephant', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Giraffe', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Hippopotamus', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Elephant', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Lion', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Crocodile', 'Giraffe', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Wild Dog', 'Baboon', 'Giraffe', 'Vulture', 'Dik Dik', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Cheetah', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Lion', 'Lion', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Giraffe', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Dik Dik', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Giraffe', 'Cheetah', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Ostrich', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Leopard', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Vulture', 'Hippopotamus', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Wild Dog', 'Hyena', 'Lion', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Elephant', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Lion', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Rhinoceros', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Elephant', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Gnu', 'Wild Dog', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Crocodile', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Crocodile', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Hyena', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Lion', 'Hippopotamus', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Rhinoceros', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Elephant', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Ostrich', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Water Buffalo', 'Lion', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Giraffe', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Rhinoceros', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Crocodile', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Giraffe', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'WartHog', 'Vulture', 'Elephant', 'Giraffe', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Water Buffalo', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Hippopotamus', 'Dik Dik', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hippopotamus', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Elephant', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Hippopotamus', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Giraffe', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Hippopotamus', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Vulture', 'Hippopotamus', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Crocodile', 'Lion', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Baboon', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Baboon', 'Baboon', 'Hippopotamus', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Hyena', 'Crocodile', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Crocodile', 'Dik Dik', 'Giraffe', 'Elephant', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Giraffe', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Hyena', 'Vulture', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'Elephant', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Dik Dik', 'Elephant', 'Gnu', 'Ostrich', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Hyena', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Wild Dog', 'Crocodile', 'Giraffe', 'Wild Dog', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Crocodile', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Elephant', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Leopard', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Hippopotamus', 'Dik Dik', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Hippopotamus', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Lion', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Crocodile', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Giraffe', 'Crocodile', 'Hippopotamus', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Dik Dik', 'Zebra', 'Elephant', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Hyena', 'Baboon', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Elephant', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Giraffe', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Leopard', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Elephant', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Vulture', 'Lion', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Hippopotamus', 'Rhinoceros', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Crocodile', 'Hippopotamus', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Elephant', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Hippopotamus', 'Hippopotamus', 'Baboon', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Dik Dik', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Giraffe', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Elephant', 'Crocodile', 'Rhinoceros', 'Dik Dik', 'Giraffe', 'Zebra', 'Lion', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Cheetah', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Elephant', 'Baboon', 'Vulture', 'Dik Dik', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Giraffe', 'Zebra', 'Wild Dog', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'WartHog', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Crocodile', 'Vulture', 'Cheetah', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Lion', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Water Buffalo', 'Elephant', 'Giraffe', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Wild Dog', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Crocodile', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Hyena', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Ostrich', 'Crocodile', 'Crocodile', 'Lion', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Rhinoceros', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Crocodile', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Hyena', 'Leopard', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Water Buffalo', 'Zebra', 'Leopard', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Baboon', 'Dik Dik', 'Elephant', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hippopotamus', 'Elephant', 'Zebra', 'Dik Dik', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Cheetah', 'Gnu', 'Elephant', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Leopard', 'Hippopotamus', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Dik Dik', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Water Buffalo', 'Hippopotamus', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Hyena', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Baboon', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Crocodile', 'Vulture', 'Elephant', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Baboon', 'Hippopotamus', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Elephant', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Elephant', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Dik Dik', 'Hippopotamus', 'Crocodile', 'Hyena', 'WartHog', 'Elephant', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hippopotamus', 'Crocodile', 'Zebra', 'Wild Dog', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Crocodile', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Giraffe', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Lion', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hippopotamus', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Lion', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Giraffe', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Dik Dik', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'Leopard', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Elephant', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Elephant', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Lion', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Elephant', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Cheetah', 'Water Buffalo', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Hyena', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Water Buffalo', 'Leopard', 'Elephant', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Hyena', 'Leopard', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Baboon', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'Leopard', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Ostrich', 'Ostrich', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Vulture', 'Crocodile', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Rhinoceros', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Hyena', 'Gnu', 'Lion', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Water Buffalo', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Water Buffalo', 'Gnu', 'Giraffe', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Elephant', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Lion', 'Dik Dik', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Hyena', 'Vulture', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Elephant', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Lion', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Rhinoceros', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Elephant', 'Baboon', 'Baboon', 'Vulture', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Vulture', 'Wild Dog', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Lion', 'Lion', 'Gnu', 'Lion', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Hippopotamus', 'Water Buffalo', 'Gnu', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Dik Dik', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Elephant', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Hyena', 'Zebra', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Giraffe', 'Wild Dog', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Crocodile', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Giraffe', 'Baboon', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'WartHog', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hyena', 'Hyena', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Hippopotamus', 'Elephant', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Vulture', 'Elephant', 'Baboon', 'Hyena', 'Crocodile', 'Gnu', 'Elephant', 'Crocodile', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Hippopotamus', 'Hyena', 'Hippopotamus', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Baboon', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Hyena', 'Gnu', 'Hippopotamus', 'Gnu', 'WartHog', 'Elephant', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Water Buffalo', 'Zebra', 'Giraffe', 'Baboon', 'Water Buffalo', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Zebra', 'Leopard', 'Vulture', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Rhinoceros', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Lion', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Crocodile', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Baboon', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Elephant', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Vulture', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Zebra', 'WartHog', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Giraffe', 'Giraffe', 'WartHog', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Thompson Gazelle', 'Gnu', 'Gnu', 'Zebra', 'Thompson Gazelle']

#print(short_animal_list)
#print(medium_animal_list)
#print(long_animal_list)

# 1) Pick an animal from the 'animal_types' list and count 
# how many there are in the 'short_animal_list'.  Then count 
# from the 'medium' list and the 'long' list

# 2) Look at the 'animal_types' list and count the number of 
# each animal from the short, medium, and ling list

elephant_count = 0
lion_count = 0
gnu_count = 0
#-------------------------------
# ---- Enter Your Code Here ----
def Counter(x,y) :
  for i in short_animal_list :
    if i == x :
      y = y + 1
      print(i)
      print('found',i)
      return (y)

Counter('Gnu',gnu_count)





#-------------------------------
# Output
print('Animal Count')
print('Elephants = ',elephant_count)
print('Lions = ',lion_count)
print("Gnu = ",gnu_count)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of problems with your code.

1. Why are you passing counter in function. Create a variable and inside function.
2. You did not catch the return value from function.
3. You indented the return value at wrong place.

Sample Code:

```
def Counter(x) :
    y = 0                  # local
    for i in short_animal_list :
        if i == x :
          y = y + 1
          print(i)
          print('found',i)
    return (y)             # return outside for loop

gnu_count = Counter('Gnu') # save return value
```

Enhanced Code:

```
def Counter(x, list_input) :
    y = 0                  # local
    for i in list_input:
        if i == x :
          y = y + 1
          print(i)
          print('found',i)
    return (y)             # return outside for loop

short_gnu_count = Counter('Gnu', short_animal_list ) # save return value
mid_gnu_count = Counter('Gnu', medium_animal_list ) # save return value
```

Answer (score 0):

The assignment inside a function does not modify the global variable. To modify a global variable from inside a function, use the global keyword as shown below.

```
def Counter(x,y) :
  for i in short_animal_list :
    if i == x :
      y = y + 1
      print(i)
      print('found',i)
      print(y)
      global gnu_count
      gnu_count = y
      return (y)
```